# Rails pass data controller to initializers file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, request, parameter-passing

I would like to configure limit and period, when the user passes information in the api request.

`config/initializers/rack_attack.rb`

```
Rack::Attack
  Rack::Attack.cache.store = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new 

  Rack::Attack.throttle('request per ip for campaigns', :limit => 6, :period => 60.seconds) do |req|
    req.api if req.path == '/api' && req.get?
  end

end
```

I have a controller that retrieves the parameters

`rate_limit_controller.rb`

```
class RateLimitController < BaseController
  # GET /api/limit= &period=
  #
  def index
    @testlimit = params[:limit]
    @testperiod = params[:period]
    render json:@testlimit
  end
end
```

is it possible to pass information from the controller to rack_attack?

Comment: Do you want to make the `limit` and `period` dynamic? Or do you want to show the values from `initializer`?

Comment: I need to pass testlimit and testperiod in rack_attack to replace the 6 and 60, I don't think thing is good idea but I can't think of another

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible to pass params to rack_attack

You can do:

```
class Rack::Attack
    Rack::Attack.cache.store = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new 
    limit_proc = proc { |req| (req.params["limit"] && req.params["limit"].to_i) || 1 } # default to 1
    period_proc = proc { |req| (req.params["period"] && req.params["period"].to_i) || 5 } # default to 5

    Rack::Attack.throttle('request per ip for campaigns', :limit => limit_proc, :period => period_proc) do |req|
        req.ip if req.path == '/' && req.get?
    end

end
```

But you should avoid doing this because it is quite easy to hack, anyone can send limit and period params and change throttling.

If you want to configure limit and period based on user then you should store mapping of user with limit and period in redis.

Then in limit_proc & period_proc loads values of limit and period from redis.